# How to deploy a azure local agent in both windows and Mac step wise?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have given the url,PAT but not sure what to give under agent pool, agent name and work folder.When we pressed enter we see a message settings saved and we run the ./run.sh command. Here we see a message "connecting to server. listening for jobs" and nothing happens.Can anyone please let us know what will be the next steps also could let us know how to build a pipeline to run the script in azure local agent.

Comment: You're basically asking for a tutorial

Comment: We have gone through tutorial and we have followed all the steps(both windows and Mac) but we were not able to succeed. We also couldn't get much help in internet. So we posted this to get some help from people who actually worked on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to create a Agent pool in VSTS before configuring the agent in local machines.

> project settings --> agent pools --> Manager and organize agent pools
>   --> add new agent pool

While configuring the agent we need to provide same agent pool name when it asks. We can give any name for agent name, which will be displayed under agent pool. Later we need to provide any directory path for workspace.

Comment: We followed the same steps and at last after entering run.cmd, we see "Listening for jobs" and agent in azure portal is online. Will you please let us know what is the next step. How do we run our script?

Comment: next we need to attach that agent pool to build/release definitions. So that the build/ release will run on that agent. If you open the build defination in EDIT mode then in the pipeline section will have a dropdown with list of agentpool. there we need to select our agent pool, then that build will run on that agent.

Comment: thanks for the information. We followed your steps and reached till pipeline execution..... but in our pipeline there is a mandatory step "webdriver-manager start" which is not executing and getting skipped. We see a error while running our scripts "Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
2018-12-19T13:35:23.3503281Z [19:05:23] E/launcher - Error code: 135
2018-12-19T13:35:23.3504669Z [19:05:23] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444"  Appreciate if you can help us

Comment: I am not sure about this error. but did you try to start the webdriver-manager manually in the agent and check if that is working fine or not. then verify with build definition.